# Postgres Update with if statement or case (don't know how to call it)

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables:

1. Users contains Id
2. ChatRoomUserLinks contains Id, RoomId (Chats.Id), UserId
3. Chats contains Id, Name, RoomType

If Chat connected with 2 people (only 2 people in one chat) I need to set RoomType = 0, if more than 2 people in one chat set RoomType = 1.

Sorry, I'm new in postgres, so I do'not know.

For example:
Chat1 contains 2 people and Chat2 contains 3 people, so in db should be looking like:

> 1 Chat1 0
>
> 2 Chat2 1

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: It would also be good, if you provide minimal schema or sample data, like i did for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe updating the chat table like this:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kzdxNPoi7fpgjshM1LSxsK/0

```
CREATE TABLE users (
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
name TEXT);

CREATE TABLE chats (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name text,
  type int);
  
CREATE TABLE chatroomuserlinks (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  chat_id int REFERENCES chats,
  user_id int REFERENCES users ) ;
  
INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('alice'), ('bob'), ('charlie');  
INSERT INTO chats (name) VALUES ('private'), ('social'); 
INSERT INTO chatroomuserlinks (chat_id, user_id) VALUES (1, 1), (1,2), (2,1), (2,2), (2,3);  
UPDATE chats
SET type = sub.type
FROM (SELECT chat_id, CASE WHEN count(l.user_id) <= 2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as type
      FROM chatroomuserlinks l group by l.chat_id) sub 
WHERE sub.chat_id = id;
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir! That's what I needed!